# Changing a derailleur

Tags: derailleur

Can I change a deraiileur? Where is one suitable for this bike?

I commute about 40km round trip. Both my bikes were stolen last night and I recovered one dumped nearby with the derailleur broken and not working anymore. No one sells bike parts in this country so I'm trying to work out if this is worth fixing. Bikes are mostly rubbish here, but very expensive so I'm not keen on buying another one if I can help it.

The red box on the deraiileur is where there is some sort of washer missing. The deraiileur is held in place and at an angle by this. I tried just chopping a washer in half and putting it in and it holds it on but not in place. So the deraiileur is too high instead of held clear of itself.
[image]
[image: Bicycle]

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is: Yes, you can of course change a derailleur.

I must take a guess but it looks like a fairly modern *Shimano Tourney RD-TY300-SGS** which should be an easy to get part, if you can source parts at all. It is in the range of 15-20$ as a replacement part, but you'd probably need a bike mechanic unless you are confident of swapping and adjusting the RD.

*) "Fairly modern" because disc brakes are shown, RD-TY300 is the cheapest model and the SGS variant should enough to accommodate the cassette shown

However, despite it being impossible to judge from the picture what is broken respectively not working anymore, to me it doesn't look as damaged that you have to replace it in an instance.

Your bike being stolen and then dumped by the road makes it more likely that it just fell on the derailleur and (most likely) the derailleur/derailleur hanger is bent or rough handling messed with the cable (tension), so that poor or even no shifting is the result.

You probably need to come up with more details on its misfunction to get better help, but you might check related threads such as

- [How to straighten a bent derailleur hanger?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/how-to-straighten-a-bent-derailleur-hanger)
- [Rear derailleur bent (not derailleur hanger)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/67073/rear-derailleur-bent-not-derailleur-hanger)
- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derailleur+adjustment

I hope that helps as a starting point.

*Update*

Base on your description

> The derailleur looks ok, but it comes off the bike, there's some sort of internal washer that holds it on, it also keeps it in a certain position, so without it, the derailleur doesn't work [...]

and the marking on the picture above, I think the B-tension assembly is damaged, perhaps the spring is broken or some nose snapped off, hard to judge.

Comment: It's not bent there is some sort of holding washer or something that is just missing altogether internal to part of it. It looks ok only because I straightened it out. But either way no parts available. The whole derailleur was off when I found it.

Comment: @Kilisi What exactly is the symptom? Are the pulley wheels stuck, does the cage move according to shifter input? "Holding washer" implies that the pulleys are not moving? I'm sorry, you need to be more specific, ideally a video or detailed description of the misfunction.

Comment: The deraiilleur looks ok, but it comes off the bike, there's some sort of internal washer that holds it on, it also keeps it in a certain position, so without it, the derailleur doesn't work, I'll mark it on the picture and upload again

Comment: I have a 6ft fence topped with barbed wire, I assume it was broken while getting it over as it was dumped very close

Comment: @Kilisi OK you have marked the upper bolt (I think it is called the B-bolt). I'm no pro mechanic but isn't there a spring inside that might have just snapped and it doesn't recess to the correct position?

Comment: I have no idea what should be there, hence my question

Comment: @Kilisi So, last try... I'm talking about this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIwrqUlFdoM Hard to assess from your input but I would bet something in that assembly is broken or loose ....

Comment: Looks like most of that stuff is missing from my derailleur, where can I buy one that will ship to my country? Mid Pacific. The eclip isn't there so all the stuff like the spring and anything else is gone as well

Comment: Here's the exploded view of the component: https://dassets.shimano.com/content/dam/global/cg1SHICCycling/final/ev/ev/EV-RD-TY300-3956B.pdf - it has no Shimano parts number, so it might be that you can't get a spare and need to get a full RD, unless you can strip a compatible part. I don't know how interchangeable that part is from other Shimano components to maximize the chances of getting a fitting part. That's all I can say.

Comment: I just want to buy a new derailleur, no point trying to repair anything with no parts. Can I install a new one without breaking the chain? I don't have chain tools

Comment: I don't know where to get parts in mid-pacific but you can open the cage (just remove the screws in the pulley wheels, then you don't have to break the chain). Can't advise on shops. Good luck!